# automatically adjust the size of a minipage

Tags: graphics, minipage, wrapfigure

I'm trying to get a way to automatically adjust the size of a minipage.

I am creating a report which will have several "paragraphs" that have a floating image on the left and some text on the right of that image. The both of them ( image + text ) make together a "semantic block".

[image: The result I want]

First I did that :

```
\begin{wrapfigure}{L}{0.15\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.1\textwidth]{image}\\
    \emph{image caption with no "figure1"}
\end{wrapfigure}
Text related to this image\\
Text related to this image\\
Text not related to this image\\
```

and of course the text not related to the image was considered like the other lines of text, printing on the right of the image.

So i tried to wrap it all :

```
\begin{minipage}[c][10cm]{20cm}
\begin{wrapfigure}{L}{0.15\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.1\textwidth]{image}\\
    \emph{image caption with no "figure1"}
\end{wrapfigure}
Text related to this image\\
Text related to this image\\
\end{minipage}
Text not related to this image\\
```

but it really isn't convenient and the height is fixed.

Here is a minimal "working" code for both:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\begin{document}

\begin{wrapfigure}{L}{0.2\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.2\textwidth]{image}
    \emph{image caption with no "figure1"}
\end{wrapfigure}
Text related to this image\\
Text related to this image\\
Text not related to this image\\


\begin{minipage}[c][10cm]{20cm}
    \begin{wrapfigure}{L}{0.2\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=0.2\textwidth]{image}\\
        \emph{image caption with no "figure1"}
    \end{wrapfigure}
    Text related to this image\\
    Text related to this image\\
\end{minipage}
Text not related to this image\\

\end{document}
```

If there is a better way to do it not using minipage that would be great too.
In the end i plan to make it into a \newenvironment taking 2 parameters : image name and text so I can use it easily in the article.

Comment: Welcome. Your use of `\\ ` tells me you are doing something strange. The doube backslash should only be used in tables, it is almost never needed in normal text.

Comment: Do you simply want to have a box with an image on the left and a description/caption on the right? That is very simple and `wrapfigure` isn't needed. I think it is a strange package anyway.

Comment: Please read [what we need to see to help you properly](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/How_to_get_help).

Comment: \\ is the same as \newline no ? I use it to make a linebreak.
I made a little editing of a picture of what i want. In red is the text before and after the "box" i want to create. http://img11.hostingpics.net/pics/740360whatiwant.png

Comment: Johannes_B added a minimal working example [what we need to see to help you properly](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/How_to_get_help).

Comment: Are you using that template from Frits? Do not use templates!

Comment: what is Frits ? I use the code as provided in edited question.

Comment: By the way, good example. More experienced users don't manage to get a good example is such short time.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I am a big fan of floating environments, but if floating is not allowed, you don't have to use it.

[image: shrimpdrakeFigure]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\newcommand{\nonfloatingfigure}[3]{%
    \par\addvspace{\abovedisplayskip}
    \noindent\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
        \begin{minipage}{.5\linewidth}
            \centering
            #1\par#2\end{minipage}\begin{minipage}{.5\linewidth}
            \raggedright#3
        \end{minipage}
    \end{minipage}
    \par\addvspace{\belowdisplayskip}
}
\begin{document}
\blindtext

\nonfloatingfigure{\includegraphics[width=0.6\textwidth]{example-image-a}}{
image caption with no "figure1"}{
    The image on the left shows a Wombat, well it would, but package MWE does not provide
    a picture of a Wombat. It definitely should

}
\blindtext


\nonfloatingfigure{\includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{example-image-b}}{
image caption with no "figure1"}{
    Text related to this image
    Text related to this image
    \blindtext
}
Text not related to this image
\blindtext

\end{document}
```

Comment: exactly what i needed. Clever to use two adjacent minipages inside a big minipage. I adapted it (  \usepackage{calc} needed ) to get the left one {4cm} and the right one  {\linewidth-4cm}, it works great.

Comment: @shrimpdrake Nice to hear it works for you.